# Hover issue on DIV (css)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a really simple button using a div.
Everything's fine, except that when the mouse cursor goes over the button, the text is supposed to turn black, and the background-color white...But currently, I have to put the mouse cursor over the text to see it turn black.

Here's my CSS code :

```
.pledges_boutons {
    width: 157px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: #868686;
    }
```

and Hover :

```
.pledges_boutons:hover {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pledges_boutons">
   <a href="http://www.google.com">Click here</a>
</div>​
```

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JCWn/)

Thank you!

Comment: Please include your HTML in the question.  Do not rely on jsFiddle demo for that.  Edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace:

```
.pledges_boutons:hover {
```

With:

```
.pledges_boutons:hover, .pledges_boutons:hover a {
```

That will do the trick ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways to handle this, but essentially you need to provide a specific enough selector to override the style of the anchor when the parent is hovered.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6JCWn/1/

```
.pledges_boutons:hover a {
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are specifically styling the link to be white:

```
.pledges_boutons a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

The link is styled white using a selector that is more specific than:

```
.pledges_boutons:hover {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}​
```

So what you want to do is change it to

```
.pledges_boutons:hover,
.pledges_boutons:hover a {
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}​
```

Once you do that, you can remove the rule directly above it, since it will be made redundant:

```
.pledges_boutons a:hover {
    color:#000;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> clears the browser page cache; the browser caches css files.